# Where can I get a list of the 'Custom Tool' code generators that come with VS2K8?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, code-generation

I've used MSDataSetGenerator a fair bit and it causes a bunch of pain because the XMLSerializer rarely works on the output. Are there any other code generators that come with the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the registry in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Generators.
The subfolders indicate a specific language, i.e. the {FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC} stands for C# language.

Each generator has a CLSID that points to the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\CLSID folder.